# Excel displays #VALUE! as 0.0 in chart

Tags: microsoft-excel, charts

In this Excel sheet I have a data range where values are calculated from a formula =INDEX(...). That formula returns #VALUE! in some cases. I thought Excel would not plot those and maybe it doesn't. But if I choose to display "value" labels for the data series, the label for #VALUE! come up as 0.0. How can I tell Excel to not bother with the data labels if the value is not plotted? It looks right now that I can either:

- Live with the 0.0 which is not the most professional presentation for the graph.
- Don't show the value for the data series, which is worse than the previous because users will have to guess the values.
- Delete every 0.0 label every time I create the graphs. This is not the most efficient thing to do and if I transfer the work to someone else, they might not be willing to make this fix for every report.

What are ways to fix this problem?

This is the data being plotted.

[image]

This is the chart

[image]

This is the option selected to display the value labels.

[image]

Comment: Wrap your INDEX() formula in IFERROR: `=IFERROR(Your_Index_Formula_Here,"")`

Comment: One crucial information is missing in your question and that is the INDEX formula, producing the #Value error. Other I can point out, you have 2 situations, First whether you want to rectify the problem and then make the CHART or the Second is, want to use the ERROR row as Data Series. Let me remind you that, the DATA SERIES helps the Excel to plot the CHART! You are getting ZERO because Formula has a bug so that not produced the  RESULT.

Comment: If you are going with Error Row to plot the Chart, re-write the Formula as @Bandersnatch has suggested. IFERROR wil replace ZERO with BLANK SPACE.

Comment: @Bandersnatch the data labels are still shown as "0.0" with IFERROR(formula,""). The error check cleans the data table with empty cells, but Excel puts 0.0 instead of an empty cell for the labels.

Answer (score 1):

There are two factors that determine how Excel charts 0 and blank values.  The first is the value itself, and the second is the Hidden and Empty Cells settings.

First, make sure that Excel is returning either " " or #N/A for cells that you don't want charted.  Other values (e.g. #Value!) can be charted as a 0 by Excel.  As mentioned above, use `=IFERROR` to return either "" or NA() (which is my personal preference).

Second, go to **`Select Data>Hidden and Empty Cells`** and make sure that you've selected **Show Empty Cells as Gaps** and check **Show #N/A as an empty cell** (if you've used the NA() in your IFERROR formula.

Comment: The problem is not the chart but the data labels. There no points shown on the chart. The numbers "0.0" are data labels. These appear whether the cell value is #VALUE! or empty/blank. If I put the error check with NA(), the data labels show as #N/A.  I did select show empty cells as gaps. There is no option to Show #N/A as an empty cell.

Comment: So if your formula uses IFERROR to turn an error into "", then the label will show "" instead of "0.0", which is how Excel charts interpret the #VALUE! error.